# usepackage[modulo]{lineno} - need also linenumber on line 1

Tags: line-numbering, lineno

I use lineno to number my lines, obviously.

I need a number every 5 lines so I enabled the option *modulo*.

But, because **1 mod 5 <> 0**, the firstline does not get numbered.
And as you already guessed by now, I need that number 1...

I can easily use another package if this is impossible with *lineno*.

**screenshot**

[image: screenshot of the MWE]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[modulo]{lineno} 
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\begin{document}

    \begin{linenumbers} 
        \textbf{Oh lord, won't you give me, my linenumber 1\\}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\\
        Donec sit amet diam vel sapien commodo tempor at at sem.\\
        Praesent mollis enim mauris. Integer eu consequat neque.\\
        Nullam hendrerit laoreet fringilla.\\
        Aenean massa dolor, tristique maximus aliquet vel, hendrerit non mi.\\
        Pellentesque euismod mattis lectus, vel pretium turpis condimentum efficitur.\\
        Ut commodo ante nec risus sagittis, vitae sodales massa dictum.\\
        Quisque scelerisque pretium faucibus.\\
        Duis gravida ex lorem, et tincidunt diam mattis quis.\\
        Aenean nibh elit, pretium id leo ornare, congue mollis est.\\
        Etiam dictum viverra libero in imperdiet.\\
        Integer vel scelerisque urna, et porttitor turpis.\\
        Mauris porta molestie tincidunt. Vivamus ut rutrum urna.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\\
        Donec sit amet diam vel sapien commodo tempor at at sem.\\
    \end{linenumbers}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Everybody knows which is line number 1…

Comment: @egreg Unfortunately that is what my professor wants to hear. According to the instructions, the first line number must be preceded with a 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redefine `\themodulolinenumber` to unconditionally print the number if the line is the first. You have to restate that you want to number every five lines, in order the redefinition is taken into account.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[modulo]{lineno} 
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd\themodulolinenumber
 {\relax}
 {\relax\ifnum\value{linenumber}=1 \thelinenumber\else}
 {}{}
\appto\themodulolinenumber{\fi}

\modulolinenumbers

\begin{document}

\begin{linenumbers} 
\textbf{Oh lord, won't you give me, my linenumber 1\\}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\\
Donec sit amet diam vel sapien commodo tempor at at sem.\\
Praesent mollis enim mauris. Integer eu consequat neque.\\
Nullam hendrerit laoreet fringilla.\\
Aenean massa dolor, tristique maximus aliquet vel, hendrerit non mi.\\
Pellentesque euismod mattis lectus, vel pretium turpis condimentum efficitur.\\
Ut commodo ante nec risus sagittis, vitae sodales massa dictum.\\
Quisque scelerisque pretium faucibus.\\
Duis gravida ex lorem, et tincidunt diam mattis quis.\\
Aenean nibh elit, pretium id leo ornare, congue mollis est.\\
Etiam dictum viverra libero in imperdiet.\\
Integer vel scelerisque urna, et porttitor turpis.\\
Mauris porta molestie tincidunt. Vivamus ut rutrum urna.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\\
Donec sit amet diam vel sapien commodo tempor at at sem.
\end{linenumbers}

\end{document}
```

[image]